# pagination with wordpress in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have made testimonial page in wordpress. data is coming from database dynamically.I want to do paging in that page.can any one suggest me the proper way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress `$post` object that is passed along with every page can help you out. You need to tell WordPress that while building up the list of posts, it need to take into account the page that it's on.

To make sure that's happening, you need to adjust your page's wp_query. What you want to do is modify the current query, but change nothing else.

As the documentation puts it:

> query_posts() is meant for altering the main loop. Once you use query_posts(), your post-related global variables and template tags will be altered. Conditional tags that are called after you call query_posts() will also be altered - this may or may not be the intended result.

If that's what you're after, the following code-snippets below allows you to do just that.

```php
query_posts(
  array(
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
  )
);
```

If you are using **a custom page template** to list posts, however, you want to use a slightly different snippet (note the variable's missing 'd'):

```php
query_posts(
  array(
    'paged' => get_query_var('page')
  )
);
```

Alsol [here's some more explanation](http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html) by the author of the PageNavi plugin, and if you'd like to know more about what wp_query can do, check out the [WordPress Codex page for query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Comment: Use wp_pagenavi plugin to display pagination.